# Mysql, search in JSon field?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select

In my MySQL Database, some fields are "**JSon** *text*" fields.

Seoemtimes, I need to search/select from what these Json contain.
How should I do ?

Is there MySQL tools for achieving it ?

Thanks

Comment: See the "Efficient Access" section here: http://mysqlserverteam.com/json-labs-release-native-json-data-type-and-binary-format/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract data from json inside mysql field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357542/extract-data-from-json-inside-mysql-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://labs.mysql.com/ refeers to MySQL JSon.
It is not fit for production yet.

Using a specific JSON type, rather than VARCHAR or TEXT, is definetely in progress by the MySQL Labs'.
It can be used with the latest MySQL releases, but seems quite beta.
Anyway, it's promising.

Googling a bit provides even documentation about it.
JSON type is to be a new type for MySQL.
**it will make possible to search in Json-typed filed**, and also to insert/delete/select, etc.

Comment: Your question title says "in JSon field" so I assumed you were using the JSon type. Is your column type actually `text`?